# Applying a focus style event to a UL tagit element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, tag-it

using jquery Tagit and looking to apply a css focus to the UL tag.

I cant think of a way to do this and my attempts with jquery havent been succesful.

I tried e.g:

```
<ul name="addtags" id="addtags"></ul>

$( "#addtags" ).click(function() {
  $("#addtags").attr('id', 'addtagsfocus');
});

$( "#addtagsfocus" ).bind('clickoutside', function() {
  $("#addtagsfocus").attr('id', 'addtags'); 
});
```

which works on click, but i cant get a blur / clickoutside etc function triggering.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Give your UL a tabindex attribute:

```
<ul name="addtags" id="addtags" tabindex="1">
```

then it becomes focusable and focus/blur event now apply.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/EV4Yc/1/